# Only show top level categories on a WooCommerce home page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a new shop using the WooCommerce plugin and so far all is working 100% except now I'd like to only show the Top Level Categories on the home page instead of Categories and Sub Categories.

My shop has 4 main categories and 25-50 sub categories and it's making the home page look ugly.. is there an automatic way to only shop the top 4 catgegories or am I going to have to do this manually?

I'm using the ShopKeeper theme
http://themeforest.net/item/shopkeeper-ecommerce-wp-theme-for-woocommerce/full_screen_preview/9553045

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi you need to use woo commerce shortcode on shop page.

```
[product_categories number="4" parent="0"]
```

Comment: so simple... I feel bad now ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To show ALL top level categories:

[product_categories number="0" parent="0"]

Answer (score 0):

Just a supplemental, enter the ID of the category within parent to display the children of that category. Easily find this by going to Products > Categories, hovering over the link of the required category and finding the ID in the URI.